# Radio controlled sheep

Tags: internal-consistency, agriculture, viruses

A worldwide pandemic has killed the world's dogs and their cousins the wolves.

In sheep farming countries, dogs have been and still are an invaluable aid to sheep farmers. Some breeds will herd the sheep others guard the flock from predators and rustlers. Sheep are grazers and they don't take at all well to factory farming. They need wide open spaces to roam and forage.

This is affecting wool and food markets right now and something has to be done.

Some bright spark suggests training the sheep instead of the dogs. This is crazy for several reasons, the main two are:

(1) sheep are stupid

(2) instead of training one dog for 6 months and then getting years of work out of it, you would have to train thousands of sheep.

The most popular idea in this age of electronics is that the sheep should be be radio-controlled.

**Question**

Assuming that we don't want to do anything nasty to the sheep and we want an inexpensive radio-collar for each, how practical would it be to call the sheep home after weeks or months of grazing for shearing, medication and other necessities?

How could they be steered in the right direction and also persuaded to move - again without animal cruelty?

Comment: Facebook (the company) was actually doing active research on that a couple years ago, but with chicken instead of sheep.

Comment: Step 1: take a large island free of predators and fill it with sheep. Step 2: name it New Zealand.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Basic Reward Training**

Sheep aren't stupid and can give a lot of dogs a run for their money.

A radio collar emits a beeping noise. To the sheep, this means a load of food they really like better than grass has been dumped in the sheep yards.

The sheep will learn what the noise is and what it means pretty quickly and you can watch them actually run all the way back to the yards

I hand feed my cows and sheep for this exact reason. They come running when I call and it's easy to get them in for worming or shearing.

Plan B is radio controlled access to water. If you shut off the water where the sheep are and the sheep know there is water in the yards, they'll all move back to the yards to get water.

Plan C is training another type of animal. As the move Babe showed us, pigs can be trained to herd sheep.

Comment: Animals are generally pretty smart as long as you don’t require abstract thought, and food is a pretty good motivator!!

Comment: Nice answer (+1). Do you have any studies or examples of sheep being as clever as dogs? I'd be interested. My sister has kept both and she assures me they are comparatively dense.

Comment: http://www.bbc.com/earth/story/20170418-sheep-are-not-stupid-and-they-are-not-helpless-either

Comment: I'm pretty sure Babe wasn't a documentary. dogs will run for miles searching out individual sheep and herding them together and in all conditions. I don't think a pig would have the speed, endurance or single mindedness of an animal descended from a predator

Comment: @Thorne - Thanks for the link. I still don't think sheep are so smart. Recognising each other's faces is standard for a herd animal; dogs can recognise faces much better IMO. I do however agree that any mammal is going to respond to food and water.

Answer (score 5):

[image]Sheep will normally follow a flock leader, traditionally a castrated ram was used for this role, known as a belwether (they carried a bell). This is still done in many parts of the world.

You don't need to control the whole flock, just the belwether. Simple reward training should work fairly well.

My cat can be summoned home by radio control using exactly this means. He has a Tabcat tracker on his collar (blue disc in image) which beeps when I press the remote. I don’t have to look for him as he knows the beep means 'food reward if I come back now', so as soon as he hears it he hurtles back in from whatever hiding place he has been lurking at in the garden. Sheep may not be as smart as cats but would probably get the idea.

Comment: Your cat looks evil.

Comment: "I've been expecting you, Mr Bond"

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to create a new solution for it in order to really get the zero animal cruelty requirement met, that will take some R&D. I think it's the way to go, but while you don't reach that mark, let me suggest using some technology that already exists.

You could tie some Halloween props to drones. When the time is right, the drones will approach the sheep from the side opposite of home. The sheep will come running.

[image: A dementor prop tied to a flying drone.]

Might be cruel because the sheep will be scared (more than what they'd be with a dog). However the cruelty involved here is minimal, and to make up for that you will also be giving them some exercise.

If you want to be creative and less cruel, you could replace the dementor props with plush dogs. Bonus if those can bark. Just fly the drones around the sheep in a way that dogs would. Might be harder to set up than the dementors, though.

---

Once you have solved the problem with minimal cruelty as above, and got the time to invest into R&D, you could work towards improving and repurposing Sony's pet dog, Aibo:

[image: Sony Aibo, a robotic dog.]

Answer (score 1):

If you can check the sheep brain for activity when they want to go "home", you can simply put an electrode in their brain stimulating that area. A wire goes outside towards the RF colar (you want as little in the brain as possible). That, or intensive pavlovian training with music, but that might be difficult.

Electrodes in the brain are less dangerous than you might assume. In progressive Parkinson they sometimes put rods through the brain towards the subthalmic nucleus to stimulate it in both hemispheres (https://mayfieldclinic.com/pe-dbs.htm). It is invasive, but smaller electrodes will be fine if not rejected in the first weeks.
You don't need to do this with every sheep and risk infections and such. Just a few, preferably socially high ranking insofar they have them. The proverbs about sheep blindly following each other is very true, to the point of whole herds (in very rare cases) killing themselves because they followed another sheep that then accidentally fell off a cliff. So with a few starting home, you might have the desired effect. The "colar" can be put under the skin. The reveiver and the electrode might even be powered by the sheeps body alone with some clever techniques, never or rarely requiring a battery change.

Alternatively you might try a different approach. Robo sheep. Sometimes introducing the robo sheep and then trying the other sheep to follow them. Though I don't know enough about sheep social behaviour if they would automatically follow unknown robo sheep, you might enhance this with pavlovian training of a few to follow them with the promise of food. If this has happened once or twice for the whole herd, it might already become a group behavior to follow robo sheep.

Comment: Instead of Robo Sheep you might wish to train them to follow a Judas Goat. The problem then becomes how you convince the goat to follow commands...

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be invest in stock for Boston Dynamics. https://www.businessinsider.com/boston-dynamics-spot-robot-dog-herding-sheep-in-new-zealand-2020-5 for an article on their robo-dog (Spot!) herding sheep in New Zealand.

Comment: Nice video but that sheep-herding bit was *very* sketchy: nothing really happened.  It will be a long time before machines equal border-collies for intelligence, reaction time, speed and sheer stamina - not to mention the cost of building and maintaining a robot (battery charging problems anyone?) https://youtu.be/bzpvPMN7uCk